# Adding IDs to a list concurrently by avoiding duplicates

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

Let's say I have a list with an `id` column on a SharePoint Online website. Multiple users can concurrently enter new `ids`. For example, the last id is `56`, and two users are adding an `id` at the same time, then both the users might end up entering `57` twice.

Is there a way to fix this sort of duplication possibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint default "ID" column is unique by default and does not allow duplicate values.

If you are using custom column for id, you can set it as unique column from column settings.

**Documentation**: [Unique Columns](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-list-relationships-by-using-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632#bkmk_unique_columns)

Comment: I am using another column called `Reference Number` which by default is called `Title` in `SharePoint Online`.

Comment: It is of type single line text, so it should be supported. You can make it unique from column settings.

Comment: Where can I find this option in `column settings`? A screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: Click on settings(gear) icon > Go to list settings > Under columns section, click on Title column  > you can find the options on this column settings page.

Answer (score 1):

The default ID column that all SharePoint lists have cannot have duplicates. For this ID column, SharePoint handles concurrency problems server side.

Comment: No it's not the default one, I am using another column called `Reference Number` which by default is called `Title` in SharePoint Online.